# How to find one item in an array in mongodb/mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a fuzzy game search to search through the games in mongodb and display the items that match. There are 3 search bars meaning you can search by name, genre, or platform. The genre and platform are stored in arrays in the database and I cannot figure out how to see if one of the items in an array matches the search term. It works when there is only one item in the array, but if there are 2 or more, it doesn't work.

this is what I have now:

```
if (req.query.searchGenre) {
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.searchGenre), "gi")
    Games.find({ genre: { $in: regex } }, (err, games) => {
      console.log(regex)
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        res.render("index", { games: games })
      }
    })
  }
```

I have tried all of the array query selectors from the mongodb docs and those aren't working.

If you have any ideas, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Can you show the sample of data in `Genre` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and your query is trying to match any element from the `genre` array with the search pattern, then [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) are the operators you want

`Games.find({ genre: { $elemMatch: { $regex: regex } } }, ...)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. You did understand me correctly and I didn't think of the $regex operator. But it's still not working properly. I'm wondering if it has to do with the 3 different searches. I'll have to play around with it more. Thanks again

Comment: Are you sure you are building the correct regex? What does `escapeRegex` do? Also, if you want to filter based on all the different searches, you have to use the [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator

Comment: This is the function: `function escapeRegex(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
}`
So right now I have the 3 different searched all in separate if statements. Am I approaching this incorrectly? Should I combine them and use the $or operator?

Comment: Yes. That's what you want , I think. Unless you want to match all search terms not just at least one of them, in which case you would use the $and operator.

Comment: Keep me updated, I could walk you through it if you can't nail the query.

Answer (score 0):

MogoDb has a **findOne()** method you can call

Say

```
Games.findOne({ genre: { $in: regex } })
```

Gives just the first available item

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this already. It crashes my program when I try to use it.